# Requires Java 1.7, but running version 1.8.0_20. Shouldn't this work?

Tags: java

I am trying to install something via a jar file:

```
java -jar filename.jar'
```

I then get this error:

```
You need at least Java version 1.7 to run the installer.
However, you appear to be running version 1.8.0_20.

Please run the installer with the requisite Java version.

Aborting...
```

I am still kinda new to this, but doesn't this mean it needs Java 1.7 or higher and I am running 1.8?

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: seems like a suboptimal installer to me...

Comment: That honestly sounds like a bug in the installer you're trying to run, incorrectly detecting java version. Your best bet is to downgrade to run the installer, or contact the author to fix the bug.

Comment: It should work in general. The error message you see is probably a message generated by the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 has some bugs right now... Just install Java 7 alongside Java 8 and it should work

If you cant find a download, here's a link to the official Oracle site with at least Java SE 7:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html